# Add a class to the 'Nearest' TD from my cursor in a plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to create a plugin to add some preset style to a table cell.

**Step-by-step:**

1. User click in a cell.
2. User click on my plugin button in the toolbar
3. Select a style
4. A class attribute is add to the closest TD

I'm having a hard time with the 4th point. How can I know where my cursor is in the source? How can I select the closest TD? The cursor must be between a `<td> </td>`. If there is no TD around nothing happen.

The cursor can be between any `<Tag>` as long as they are in a `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// nearest element that surrounds your cursor
var el = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();

while (el) {
    // if element is <td>, set class attribute and break loop
    if (el.getName() == 'td') {
        el.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
        break;
    }
    // otherwise, continue with parent element
    // until you find <td> or there are no more elements
    el = el.getParent();
}
```